# Button with three line text in iOS 10 Xamarin

Tags: ios, button, xamarin.ios, uibutton, multiline

I am setting three line string title to UIButton. I am using iOS 10. But I can't set it.

What I have tried.

1. Set the UIButton title Label with the Below String.

   `String = "Before\n-\n12:00"`.

but the `\n` doesn't break the String to new line.

and also set the UIButton property to `WordWrap`.

2. When I set

   `noOfLine` to `TitleLabel` of `UIButton` but noOfLine property is `not display`.

**ScreenShot :**

[image]

**See the ScreenShot :**

the `First one is UIButton` but it is not display well as I accepted.

the `Second one is UILabel` which is display well as I expected.

I want to set it like second one.

Is there any way to set it like Second One.

Any Help be Appreciated.

Comment: plz use setAttributedTitle inplace of setTitle method of UIButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Solution I found is that below

**See the ScreenShot :**

[image]

In the UIButton set the `Title` to `Attributed`
and also set the `Title` to `centre`.

The Output is As Expected.